# I'm trying to download a Pdf file from a website using a webView in android

Tags: java, android

```
   myWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download");
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
```

I'm trying to download a Pdf file from a website using a webView in android.
I have Already Tried this.
But it is not Working

Comment: why? what happens?

Comment: @Sajad think we can probably help you here but we need to know what goes wrong with this code, error logs would be good.

Comment: @Elemental there is no error.

Comment: I navigate to that page of the website but when I pressed that pdf link nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

be careful that needed permissions are added in manifest . try this code :

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```